# Binding to the "load" event of images that are dynamically loaded into JavaScript

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have some code that uses JavaScript templates to create some HTML, including some `<img />` tags. For our purposes, it looks like this:

```
$("myButton").click(function() { $("myDiv").html(
    'lots of html included <img class="A" /> tags');
```

Now, I'd like to have a method that replaces all `<img />` that have `class="A"` with a `<div />` with appropriate background-images and the like. (This is a hack to use `border-radius` to make square images into round ones.) This method looks roughly like this:

```
function replaceA()
{
    var imageUri = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).replaceWith('<div class="B" style="background-image: url(' + imageUri + ')"></div>');
}
```

But here's the catch. I want to run this method on all `img.A`s, no matter how they show up on my site---whether in the HTML, or inserted through a template method like the above, or even loaded with Ajax `$("myDiv").load(...)`. And this appears to be nontrivial, since even with `$(".A").live(...)`, the event handler never gets fired. In short, the following  code does not work:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MyDiv"></div>
<script>
    $(".A").live("load", function ()
    {
        alert(this);
    });

    $("#MyDiv").html('stuff <img class="A" src="http://code.google.com/images/code_logo.png" /> more stuff');
</script>
```

Any ideas as to how I can perform this trick?

Comment: Are you on the latest version of jQuery? 1.3.x doesn't support `live` for any but the most basic mouse and keyboard events, but (according to the API; I didn't actually test this) full support for all events was added in 1.4.

Comment: Indeed, as you can see from my sample code, I'm on 1.4.2. Lots of forums on the internet seem to run across the same "according to documentation, it works... but in reality it doesn't" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [DOM mutation events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_Events) . This (untested) [JQuery plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/) may also be of some use.

Comment: Ugh, I hope I don't have to step outside the confines of my comfortable jQuery :P. Sadly that plugin doesn't work for the `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` event, so I'd have to roll my own. But this is the first solution I've seen in all my browsing that seems to have a chance of working, so... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I didn't think your question was written very clearly but I decided to try to help anyways. How about this...

```
<div id="MyDiv">
<p>original image: <img class="A"  src="http://code.google.com/images/code_logo.png" /></p>
<button type="button" id="button">Add Image</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#MyDiv').append('<p>new image: <img class="A"  src="http://code.google.com/images/code_logo.png" /></p>');
});

function replaceA(){
    $('.A').each(function(){
        var imageUri = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).replaceWith('<div class="B" style="display:block; width:200px; height:50px; border:1px solid red; background-image: url(' + imageUri + ')"></div>');
    });
}

var int = self.setInterval('replaceA()',100);
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm yes, fair enough, I suppose `setInterval` would work pretty well. Thanks. Careful about using string parameters to it though; that way you're paying the cost of an `eval` every time. Just `setInterval(replaceA, 100)` would work fine.

Comment: hey, I just happened to come across an article by Eric Hynds that explains the right way to do what you need. http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-create-event/ Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
<div id="MyDiv">
<button type="button" id="button">Add Image</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#MyDiv').append('<p>new image: <img class="newimage"  src="http://code.google.com/images/code_logo.png" /></p>');

    $('.newimage').each(function(){
        alert('ready??'); //comment out when ready
        var imageUri = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).replaceWith('<div class="B" style="display:block; width:200px; height:50px; border:1px solid red; background-image: url(' + imageUri + ')"></div>');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This misses the entire point of the question, which is to have a solution that works with dynamically-inserted elements, e.g. ones inserted after the user presses a button or some third-party script injects content into my page. You'll notice that in my example the attempt at replacement came _before_ the insertion---this was intentional, since I have no control over when the insertion occurs.